# how can I get the list of file names using the log committ message as filter in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

need to get list of file names that got modified or newly added to the SVN for specific log message

I tried using the SVN list and SVN status, it returns the complete list of files that is present in SVN and list of files that is modified in my local but not yet committed. I need list of file names that got modified or newly added to the SVN for specific log committ message.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did my answer help you resolve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If not, please leave a comment or [edit] your question and tell us where you're having problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The command `svn log -v` will output a list of affected files for the each commit.

From `svn help log`:

```
  With -v, also print all affected paths with each log message.
  Each changed path is preceded with a symbol describing the change:
    A: The path was added or copied.
    D: The path was deleted.
    R: The path was replaced (deleted and re-added in the same revision).
    M: The path's file and/or property content was modified.
```

For more information, refer to the [Red Bean Book on svn log](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).